# Is C# property pattern evaluated from left to right?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I have the following code:

```cs
bool CheckStream(Stream stream) => 
    stream.CanSeek && stream.Length < 42;
```

I want to change it to:

```cs
bool CheckStream(Stream stream) => 
   stream is { CanSeek: true, Length < 42 };
```

Now I wonder, it this save? Meaning, is CanSeek evaluated before length in the property pattern? Because if not, it could throw a "NotSupportedException".

Can I expect property pattern always to be evaluated from left to right?

PS: When I tried it in C# Interactive it worked. And it throws the Exception, if I put `Length: < 42` before `CanSeek: true`. But I wondered if this is defined this way. I didn't found anything about that. If not, I think it would be possible that the code behaves different after optimization.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#positional-pattern

Comment: @KieranDevlin Pattern matching doesn't introduce overhead. [See here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGADAAQY4B0AkgPIDchGAzOVqQMKkDehp/5VhhSkAsgAoAygBdYAQwC2pAM6yYigJQ8+A3QEsAZqXGr5Svcp6c5AO0kwYAaxClZAVxgAaUgBkYNgHNpAAsXAB4UdgBfDR1dfl4CeOTyHABOcQAiAE0YAAdMjUYklKi40jKCKKA==)

Answer (score 4):

The order is not specified according to the [draft specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern), emphasis mine:

> Given a match of an expression `e` to the pattern `type { property_pattern_list }`, it is a compile-time error if the expression `e` is not pattern-compatible with the type `T` designated by `type`. If the `type` is absent, we take it to be the static type of `e`. [...]
>
> At runtime, [...] each `property_subpattern` field or property is read and its value matched against its corresponding pattern. The result of the whole match is false only if the result of any of these is false. ***The order in which subpatterns are matched is not specified***, and a failed match may not match all subpatterns at runtime.

So no, you should not expect that the properties are evaluated from left to right.

Comment: That's talking about sub-patterns during positional matching as it's one of the sub-headers of that section (I think). Either way there's a broader section later on in the document called ["Order of evaluation in pattern-matching"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#order-of-evaluation-in-pattern-matching) which basically says the compiler is allowed to re-order and properties should be side-effect free. This is a *draft* proposal and I know we're slow on formally adopting so I wonder if any guarantees have changed